# Removing binary tree element

Tags: c, binary-tree

Before this i could run it and it worked but it wasnt actually adding anything into the binary tree now after sugegstions i have updated my code.

**I updated my code**

But now when i type in the first student its ok. as soon as i insert second student it breaks down.
and keeps on printing.

Already Exist infinite amount of times and i dont know why
help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct treenode
{
char name[50];
int id;
float mark[10];
struct treenode *left;
struct treenode *right;//binary tree 
} myTree;


void insert_student(myTree **root) {
   char name[50];
   myTree *temp = malloc(sizeof(myTree));
   printf("enter name of student: ");
   scanf("%s", name);
   printf("enter ID: ");
   scanf("%d", &temp->id);
   strcpy(temp->name,name);
   temp->left = NULL;
   temp->right = NULL;
   myTree *temp_root = *root;
   if(*root == NULL) {
      *root = temp;
   }
   else
   {
       while (temp_root != NULL)
     {
       if (strcmp(name, temp_root->name) == 0)
          {
           printf("Already exists\n");
           } 
       else if (strcmp(name, temp_root->name) > 0)
            {
           if(temp_root->right == NULL)
               {
                temp_root->right = temp;
               }
           temp_root = temp_root->right;
            } 
          else {
           if(temp_root->left == NULL)
                 {
                temp_root->left = temp;
                 }
           temp_root = temp_root->left;
               }
       }
   }
}


int main(){ 
 int option;
 int r=0;    

 myTree *root = malloc(sizeof(myTree));
 root = NULL;
 char nameholder[50];
 while (r != 1)
  {
    printf ("choose one of the following options\n");                                 
    printf ("1-Introduce new student\n");    
    printf ("2-Remove Student\n");
    printf ("3-Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&option);                               
    myTree *temp,*ptr = malloc(sizeof(myTree));
    myTree *prev = malloc(sizeof(myTree)); 
    temp=root;
    switch(option)
       {
          case 1:                                           
                    insert_student(&root);      
          break;

         case 2:
          ptr=root;
          printf("Enter name of student you want to remove\n");
          scanf("%s", nameholder);
          while(ptr != NULL && strcmp(nameholder,ptr->name)==0)
             {
              prev=ptr;
              if(strcmp(nameholder,ptr->name)>0)                       
               {
               ptr = ptr->right;                                                    
               }
              if(strcmp(nameholder,ptr->name)<0)                         
                 {
                  ptr=ptr->left;                                               
                  }                                             
             }

               if(root == NULL) 
                 {
              printf("There is nothing in the tree\n");
                }
          else if(root != NULL){
          printf("Found the student you want to delete...\n");                                                     
          if ((ptr->left == NULL) && (ptr->right == NULL))
               {
               //if the node to delete is to the left of root
                  printf("DEBUG 1\n");
                    if (prev->left == ptr) 
                     { printf("DEBUG 2\n");
                       prev->left = NULL;
                       free(ptr);
  printf("It has been Deleted and the left is now connected to NULL\n");                 
                     }                                                      
        //if the node to delete is to the right of root
              else if (prev->right == ptr)
                 {
                 printf("DEBUG 4\n");
                 prev->right = NULL;
                 free(ptr); 
  printf("It has been Deleted and the right has been set to NULL\n");                   
                  }
         printf("DEBUG 5\n");
                         }           
      else if((ptr->left == NULL || ptr->right == NULL))
          {
          printf("This node has 1 child...\n");
           if(ptr->left != NULL)
             { printf("DEBUG 7\n");
               prev->left = ptr->left;
               free(ptr);
printf("Node has been Deleted and the previous node skips to the LEFT\n");
              } printf("DEBUG 8\n");
        if(ptr->right != NULL)
            { printf("DEBUG 9\n");
            prev->right = ptr->right;
           free(ptr);
printf("Node has been Deleted and the previous node skips to the RIGHT\n");
            }
        printf("DEBUG 10\n");
     }
         printf("DEBUG 11\n");
         if(ptr->left != NULL && ptr->right != NULL)
           {
           printf("This node has 2 children\n");
           }
           printf("DEBUG 12\n");                                          
 }                              
  break;

   case 3:
   r=1;
   break;

   default:
   printf("Not an option\n");
   r=1;
   break;


   }// end of switch - tree            


  }//end of infinite option loop - tree

 }//end of main
```

Also can someone check out my remove case is it wrong?

Comment: ? anyone checked this yet?

Comment: ill give it a look in a few mins...

Comment: On the first look there are many problems in your code. Even adding doesn't seem to work. I'll try to rewrite it in an answer.

Comment: owh i watched a video online and followed the logic seems to be right

Comment: Thanks a lot i have been working on this for the past week now including a linked list

Comment: Your lookup logic is faulty. Add a `printf("%p %p\n", prev, ptr);` right after the search loop, and see that they are equal. Better yet, do it with a debugger.

Comment: @user58697 just noticed i put in && for the null and equal when it should be or.i am gonna change that and see if it fixes everything.

Comment: @user58697 it gives a segfault, i think its because it goes to NULL and it can strcmp, that means it never reaches the same name.. why?

Comment: while(ptr != NULL || strcmp(nameholder,ptr->name)==0)

Answer (score -1):

As @sstefan said that there are many problems in the code and your assumption that insertion is working fine is not correct.

To explain the behavior. You are adding new nodes, but you are not attaching them to the tree ever. So all your tree ever has is the root.
This is because you first reach to NULL and then assign it a node, but the parent from where you came does not get to know about this node.

One way is to store that node in a prev pointer and attach your newly created node to it.

Other way is to first input the values in a temp node and then just attach it the right place.

```
void insert_student(my_tree **root) {
       char name[50];
       my_tree *temp = malloc(sizeof(my_tree));
       printf("enter name of student: ");
       scanf("%s", name);
       printf("enter ID: ");
       scanf("%d", &temp->id);
       temp->name = name;
       temp->left = NULL;
       temp->right = NULL;
       my_tree *temp_root = *root;
       if(*root == NULL) {
          *root = temp;
       }
       else
       {
           while (temp_root != NULL) {
           if (strcmp(name, temp_root->name) == 0) {
               printf("Already exists\n");
               return;
           } else if (strcmp(name, temp_root->name) > 0) {
               if(temp_root->right == NULL) {
                    temp_root->right = temp;
               }
               temp_root = temp_root->right;
           } else {
               if(temp_root->left == NULL) {
                    temp_root->left = temp;
               }
               temp_root = temp_root->left;
           }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

The second problem I found is that your while loop is not having correct condition and if the string you are finding is not at root, it won't enter the loop. Even if it as root Otherwise it will just be an infinite loop.

Now to explain the debug statements, as your ptr always points to root which never had any children nodes, goes through those if conditions only.

Comment: what is the line here suppost to mean

Comment: if(temp == NULL)
                 else

Comment: @sstefan / Vimarsh is there anyway to do this without ** pointer to pointer? i just dont get them.

Comment: ** pointer is to pass a pointer as call by reference to the function. You can use this code inline to not do that.

Comment: Well you should. The reason behind pointer to pointer is that if tree is empty you need to assign first entry(student) to root... and if your function was declared like `insert(my_tree *root)` you would not be able to assign anything to root, since it is only the copy of actual root

Comment: i havent really used functions.. i am new to programming only 1 month.. how would i refer to this in main?

Comment: i put in the main   insert_student()  but i get error. i dont know how to do it

Comment: Just put this code in the main and replace *root with root as you no longer need to dereference it.

Comment: @johnleno `my_tree *root = NULL; insert_student(&root);`

Comment: @sstefan why is it &root inside the insert_studet?

Comment: @Vimarsh i got it to run and it seems good as if it works but do you  think there is any problems with the removing part? case 2

Comment: @Vimrash btw its not temp->name = name you have to use strcpy

Comment: @johnleno Yup. you got me there about strcpy. About case 2: I told you in the answer about the while loop condition, that it should be "not equal to"(!=) instead of "equal to"(==) when comparing the string. I think the reason would be clear if you do a dry run once.